# C++ struct needed in Obj-c.h function prototype

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have written an obj-c wrapper to connect Swift and C++. One of the methods

```
- (bool) getParamInfo:(int) paramId parameter:(Parameter *) info;
```

needs the Parameter struct which is in the c++ file.

I tried declaring `struct Parameter` in the obj-c header but it wont compile due to an `expected a type` error.

I cannot move the Parameter struct from the c++ file into the obj-c.mm file.

How is this issue solved so that the objective-c header can compile and expose the method in the wrapper?

Comment: maybe declare it like - (bool) getParamInfo:(int) paramId parameter:(void *) info; then cast to Parameter in the .mm file?

Comment: true, that works :) I just wondered if there was another way. e.g. extern for a type (struct) from c++ that would expose it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by including the C++ Header that include **Parameter** struct

in **Parameter.hpp:** *C++ Header*

```
typedef struct{
int paramId;
} Parameter;
```

in **Param.hh**: *Objective-C++ Header*

```
#import "Parameter.hpp"
- (bool) getParamInfo:(int) paramId parameter:(Parameter *) info;
```

in **Swift-Bridging-Header.h**:

```
#import "Param.hh"
#import "Parameter.hpp"
```

in the Swift file

```
var pa = Parameter(paramId: 0) /* Create a struct */
let f = Param().getInfo(0, parameter: &pa)
```